# FastAPI: sending model in get method (TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window')

Tags: python, api, get, fastapi, webapi

I'm building an API using *FastAPI* where I have an `Offer` model that does not have an ID, but I check if an offer exists by comparing its attributes (ID of the person who offered, the amount of the offer, the type of offer, etc.). The model structure:

```
class Offer(BaseModel):
    trader_id: str
    share_id: str
    type: Literal["sale", "purchase"] = Field(default="sale | purchase")
    price: int = Field(gt=0, description="The price must be greater than zero")
    status: Literal["open", "closed"] = Field(default="open")
```

I'm trying to write a get method that will receive an Offer object and return according to a comparison of the attributes whether it exists or not:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal

app = FastAPI(title="BurseAPI")

@app.get("/burse_api/v1/offers/offer-exists", tags=["Offers"])
async def offer_exists(offer: Offer) -> bool:
    for existing_offer in DB.offers: # A list containing all the offers
        if offer == existing_offer:
            return True
    return False
```

When I try to test the method through Swagger UI I get this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

[image: Screenshot from the testing in Swagger]

I really don't want to enter all the parameters separately, what can be done about it?

Comment: If you are posting data to the server it should be POST, not GET.